# JQuery integer division function seems not working

Tags: jquery, division

This is my first jQuery application. I'm trying to do a simple division but it’s not working and i have been searching on google  for hours and still  I have no idea what is wrong. Can you please help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $("btnvalidate").click(function () {

       var ilk = $("#txtilk").val();
       var ikinci = $("#txtikinci").val();
       var sonuc;
       if (kontrol == true) {
           sonuc = Math.floor(parseInt(ilk) / parseFloat(ikinci));

           alert(sonuc);

       }
   });

   function kontrol() {
       var ilk = $("#txtilk").val();
       var ikinci = $("#txtikinci").val();

       if (ilk < ikinci) {


           alert("kesirli sonuc");
       }
       else {
           return true;
       }
   }
  </script>
  </head>

    <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type="text" id="txtilk" />
  <input type="text" id="txtikinci" />

 <input type="button" value="Validate" id="btnvalidate" />    

 </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: what I see in first moment, is that you address btnvalidate wrong, you need to do this $("#btnvalidate").

Comment: Also this line — `if (kontrol == true) {` should probably be `if (kontrol() == true) {`, assuming you want to compare the result of the `kontrol` function with `true`, instead of the `kontrol` function itself. However, please note that when asking questions on Stack Overflow about code, the question must describe the specific problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Don't edit your question to remove the errors -- now the answers make no sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code the first one is the validete button selector, it should be
$("#btnvalidate")

the second one is if (kontrol == true), this should be if (kontrol() == true)

please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/victorrseloy/4gc2n/

js:

```
  $("#btnvalidate").click(function () {
           var ilk = $("#txtilk").val();
           var ikinci = $("#txtikinci").val();
           var sonuc;
           if (kontrol() == true) {
               sonuc = parseInt(ilk) / parseFloat(ikinci);

               alert(sonuc);

           }



       });


       function kontrol() {
           var ilk = $("#txtilk").val();
           var ikinci = $("#txtikinci").val();

           if (ilk < ikinci) {


               alert("kesirli sonuc");
           }
           else {
               return true;
           }
       }
```

html

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" id="txtilk" />
  <input type="text" id="txtikinci" />

 <input type="button" value="Validate" id="btnvalidate" />    

 </form>
```

Comment: could u upload all the code to  jsfiddle? so I can check what is happening to you.